# Coupon code button problem!

Tags: checkout, javascript, coupon

I have 1 issue confusing. 
-When i am in `checkout cart page`. I cant click button apply `coupon code`.
**Javascrip seems it does not work** ( I try with input empty but no validate or any reaction).
But if I am in `checkout onepage`. I can do it.
I check template path hint and see them using 1 template `default/template/checkout/cart/coupon.phtml`
Someone can explain it?

Update code `coupon.phtml`

```
<form id="discount-coupon-form" action="<?php echo $this->getFormActionUrl() ?>" method="post">
    <div class="discount">
        <div class="discount-form">
            <input type="hidden" name="remove" id="remove-coupone" value="0" />
            <div class="field-wrapper">
                <input class="input-text" type="text" id="coupon_code" name="coupon_code" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getCouponCode()) ?>" />
                <div class="button-wrapper">
                    <button type="button" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Discount Codes')) ?>" class="button2" onclick="discountForm.submit(false)" value="<?php echo $this->__('Discount Codes') ?>"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Discount Codes') ?></span></span></button>
                    <?php if(strlen($this->getCouponCode())): ?>
                        <button type="button" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Cancel')) ?>" class="button2 cancel-coupon" onclick="discountForm.submit(true)" value="<?php echo $this->__('Cancel') ?>"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Cancel') ?></span></span>
                        </button>
                    <?php endif;?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var discountForm = new VarienForm('discount-coupon-form');
discountForm.submit = function (isRemove) {
    if (isRemove) {
        $('coupon_code').removeClassName('required-entry');
        $('remove-coupone').value = "1";
    } else {
        $('coupon_code').addClassName('required-entry');
        $('remove-coupone').value = "0";
    }
    return VarienForm.prototype.submit.bind(discountForm)();
}
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: without checking code,it cannot be possible to decide the issue

Answer (score 0):

Replace coupon code button to this.

```
<button title="Apply Coupon" onclick="discountForm.submit(false)" value="Apply Coupon"><span><span>Apply Coupon</span></span></button>
```